# Business test data for automated tests

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, test-data

My automated tests (at the GUI/API levels) require to have already existing test data - like users or privileges assigned to them.
I want them to be stable and able to run independently every time so I cannot hardcode this data. Also, I wouldn't like to create them as a part of test as it could make my tests more brittle.

Lets assume that a system is a basic CRUD for books management.
I'd like to automate test case like "modify book name".
In order to do this, first I need to have already created book and user with privilege to modify it. 
Similar situation occurs for most of other test cases.

Should I prepare this test data before tests, e.g. using API interface? Or maybe I should mock it somehow?

Comment: Could you clarify (1) where & how the data is stored (local? remote? SQL server? Embedded DB?), and (2) whether the UI is a browser interface or a client app (and if so what platform)?  The platform & architecture are significant to your question, they will enable certain solutions while excluding others.

Answer (score 1):

**I would suggest:**

1. Create all the users and books you need in-suite setup.
2. Drive your test through data-driven through CSV or JSON
3. Delete the configuration in suite-tear down

**in CSV put in all the details like:**

user,privilege, action, resource, expected output

**a sample CSV would be:**

```
user,privileg, action, resource, expected output
test1,admin, delete, v1/book/1,successfly deleted
test1,basic, delete, v1/book/1,you don't have enough privillege
test1,basic, get, v1/book/1, Have a nice reading time
```

In this case, your test is driven through CSV you don't have to do anything in test because privilege, expected message, character everything is defined in CSV itself.